# KDE: Автоматическая замена последовательности символов "---" (три дефиса) на "—" (тире)

Tags: kde

Как сделать в KDE, чтобы при вводе трёх дефисов ("---") они автоматически (сразу или после нажатия пробела, когда именно не столь важно) заменялись на тире ("—")?

Comment: можно это сделать без участия kde, с помощью [xcompose](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=xcompose)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, так получилось, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как советуют в комментариях, желаемого поведения можно добиться, назначив клавишу <kbd>[Compose](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose)</kbd>. В KDE соответствующая настройка находится в разделе `Устройства ввода/Дополнительно/Положение клавишы Compose`.

Назначив эту клавишу можно будет вводить тире через комбинацию <kbd>Compose</kbd> + `три дефиса`. Вводить тире становится особенно удобно, если учитывать, что при наборе трёх дефисов необязательно держать <kbd>Compose</kbd> нажатой. То есть так тоже работает:

1. Нажимаем <kbd>Compose</kbd>
2. **Отпускаем** <kbd>Compose</kbd>
3. Набираем три дефиса

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но ведь тогда я не смогу вводить дефисы вообще? Я добавил такое правило: `<minus> <minus> <minus> : "—"`, теперь три дефиса преобразуются в тире, но если я ввожу один дефис, то ничего не вводится. То есть если я набрал `дефис`, `символ1`, `символ2` и оба эти символа не дефисы, то введётся только `символ2`.

Comment: да, вы правы. я совсем забыл: символы вообще будут «проглатываться».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, скажите, пожалуйста, а считается хорошим тоном удалять такие комментарии (или зачем вы его удалили)?

Comment: комментарии, в идеале, здесь вообще подлежат удалению. вся существенная информация должна находиться в вопросе/ответе. а уж если в комментарии написано что-нибудь неправильное/бесполезное — то нет причин, чтобы его не удалить.